# Disk space not freed after deleting file and killing processes holding it

Tags: debian, disk-usage, raspbian

I'm using the latest version of Raspberrypi os, and I had a big archive file (from librespot) in the /var/cache that took all the disk space available (57GB). I deleted it using `rm`, but the `df` command still showed that the disk was full. I checked for processes holding it using the command `sudo lsof +L1` and pulseaudio was. I killed the process, and when running again the command `sudo lsof +L1` the process was gone. But when running the `df` command again, the disk space was still filled. I tried restarting the system, but the disk space was still filled, and pulseaudio reappeared in the output of `sudo lsof +L1`. The file is not present in the filesystem anymore (not showing up with `ls`).

Here is the line from the output of `sudo lsof +L1`

`pulseaudi  915      pi    6u   REG    0,1 67108864     0 2054 /memfd:pulseaudio (deleted)`

How can I free the space taken by this file? Why is this process still holding to the file even though it was killed?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question has been deleted on the other site.